# How to create a eraser for a drawing html app?

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I am new on EaselJS and I want to create an eraser as brush. This is what I am using for drawing but I want to do the same thing with transparent.

```
//brush tool
var brush = new createjs.Bitmap(app.loader.getResult('brush'));
brush.name = 'brush';
brush.x = 50;
brush.y = -34;
brush.addEventListener('click', this.brushHandler);
this.toolsContainer.addChild(brush);    


this.brushSizes = new createjs.Container();
this.brushSizes.x = brush.x + 40;
this.brushSizes.y = brush.y - 20;
this.brushSizes.visible = false;
this.toolsContainer.addChild(this.brushSizes);


for(var p = 0; p < this.sizes.length; p++){
    var size = new createjs.Shape();
    size.name = 'size'+p;
    size.graphics.beginFill('#FFFFFF');
    size.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,this.sizes[p]);
    size.addEventListener('click', this.brushHandler);     
    size.x = (p==1) ? p * 40 : p * 45; 
    this.brushSizes.addChild(size);
}
```

Comment: Using a "transparent" brush won't affect the canvas since you apply transparency over color. You must find a way to "delete" the color applied under the brush position and replace it with "nothing". I would post code if I had an idea on how to do that.

Comment: Have a look at the AlphaMaskReveal sample in the EaselJS GitHub. You can preview it here: http://createjs.com/Demos/EaselJS/AlphaMaskReveal.html

Comment: So you tell me to create in eraser function another drawer function to remove the points?